# Inspect variables in vector/matrices from Eigen Library

Tags: visual-c++, eigen, inspector

Does anybody know how to inspect the value of matrices or vectors when debugging programs using the Eigen Library in MS-Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5):

For newer versions of VS (2012 and higher) download [eigen.natvis](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/246af84e462db0dd95ca68f8b5cca6e496b71cf3/debug/msvc/eigen.natvis?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default%20eigen.natvis) and simply add it to your C++ project (as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Developer%27s_Corner#Debugging_under_Visual_Studio) there is an extension file in [debug/msvc](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/tip/debug/msvc/eigen_autoexp_part.dat) for that purpose.

Comment: As described in the linked wiki, I tried adding visualizer.dat into autoexp.dat for MSVC 2015 after the [Visualizer] section, but it didn't work. After restarting MSVC the Eigen matrices and vectors are as opaque as always.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe: For VS2015, you need to use .natvis file, not autoexp.dat.